# Git: Delete a specific file using bfg (bfg-repo-cleaner)

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

I am trying to delete a file permanently from the Git history, because it contains sensitive data.

To do this, I am using `bfg`: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

The file is called `app/config.json`.

However there are other files called `config.json` in other folders that I don't want deleted.

I tried the following:

```
git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-repo.git
bfg --delete-files app/config.json my-repo.git
```

but I get the error message:

```
Error: *** Can only match on filename, NOT path *** - remove '/' path segments
```

How do I delete just this specific file?

Answer (score 3):

"Warning: Once you have pushed a commit to GitHub, you should consider any data it contains to be compromised. If you committed a password, change it! If you committed a key, generate a new one." https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

```
cd my-repo/app
bfg --delete-files config.json
```

You could also try:

```
bfg --replace-text config.json
```

Comment: I did a git mirror as suggested by the docs on the bfg website. For this do I need to do a normal clone

Comment: When I run your command on the repo it says:  `C:\path\to\some-repo\app is not a valid Git repository.`

Comment: @YahyaUddin you should run the command from repo's root. In your example: C:\path\to\some-repo